# How can I schedule a python script inside a conda env to run every n minutes?

Tags: python, cron, conda

I have a python script getData.py on my mac which I would like to run once every 10 minutes or so. I am aware of crontab and have tried it before using virtual envs. However I need help on how this can be achieved within a conda env that I do my work with.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a bash script that I run as if it were regular python whenever I need a specific conda environment.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
source <conda-directory>/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
# Uncomment this line to include .profile for environment variables
# source ~/.profile

conda activate <name-of-env>
python "$@"
```

Save this to a file and run

```
chmod +x <filename>
```

to make it executable.

Now you can run this script instead of python. I called my file `conda_python`, and saved it in my home directory. To run a python script with this environment do

```
~/conda_python script.py
```

This should also work from `crontab`.

Comment: Thanks @Marcel, I did the following

`source /opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d

conda activate data
python "$@"`

and saved it as a cron.sh. Folowed by chmod-ing it as you mentioned. I then ran it on the terminal using 
`/Users/ananth/Documents/Data/cron.sh`

This ran for the first time and then I created a crontab entry like so-
`*/10 * * * * /Users/ananth/Documents/Data/cron.sh` (for running the script every 10 mins....and waited.
I got the error message upon checking /var/ananth/mail - 
/Users/ananth/Documents/Data/cron.sh: line 6: conda: command not found
Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to run `source /opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh`, with the `conda.sh`